# How can I change the layout of pages in a TabView, SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-scrollview

I have to create a view like this:

[image]

The next and previous cards should be slightly visible along the side edges.

That's a point, i can't figure out how to do that. This should not be just a scroll view, because when the next and previous card is pulled back enough, new card should become centered. That is, when there is no pressing on the screen, there should always be a card in the center.

I was able to implement this well **without cards on the sides** using TabView.

```
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            let size = $0.size
            TabView(selection: $currentPage, content: {
                ForEach(fakedCards) { card in
                    // another part of code
                }
            })
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
```

What i get:

[image]

```
              ↓
```

[image]

```
              ↓
```

[image]

But any manipulations with TabView did not lead me to the desired result.
Maybe i can achieve it using ScrollView instead of TabView but i don't understand how.

***I would be immensely grateful for any thoughts or suggestions.***

Comment: [This is possible in iOS 17 with `scrollTargetLayout`.](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-scrollview-snap-with-paging-or-between-child-views)

Comment: @Sweeper exactly that i want but it is available only from iOS 17+, when my target is iOS 15+ :(
Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: It isn't possible for iOS 13-16 you have to create your own version

Comment: @loremipsum This is my question. I don't understand how I can do this. Could you please explain the approximate essence.

Comment: ScrollView + ScrollViewReader + Rectangle maybe…. HStack + DragGesture + offset, or use UIKit… There are several packages online you can examine. This is a common question/setup. There are many approaches. I don’t have a specific one to share.

Comment: Create custom tab bar (there is needed item and selected item properties inside, button where you will set selectedItem = item) and set up view like you need from your source. Default tab bar left just for track selectedItem.

Comment: @Arsienij thank you very much, I will definitely try it!